# unwanted time delay in latch-circuit with diode

Tags: diodes, latch

I am trying to use the following circuit. It somehow does what I want, but I would like to

a) **get rid of the time delay**.

b) would like to **understand**, why the time delay gets that high (and also, why its getting higher, the longer its functioning without a reset (up to 15seconds))

Short explanation for the circuit: My **SW1** is just me giving one **5V pulse** to the circuit.
This leads to a latch, my Q1 is switching, thats fine.
The **reset** **isnt a pulse**, I am putting the wire to the ground and I am leaving it there. But getting the voltage down needs to much time, what can I do ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAaJq9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome! Where is your output? The collector of Q1?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, thats true. I am measuring at the Collector of Q1. I will add this to the circuit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have over 78 mA of base current through Q1.  That's a lot.  For only 24 mA of collector current, that's a **whole lot**.
2. You don't say how long "to(o) much time" is.  What is your timing requirement.

Instant analysis / mystic vision / inspired babble:

Both Q1 and Q2 are heating up due to the excessive Q1 base current.  This decreases the Q2 Vbe because a silicon transistor base-emitter junction forward voltage has a well-documented negative temperature coefficient.  But while D1 has a similar Vf and tempco, it is not subjected to the same internal heating.

There is no reason for D1 in the circuit, and in this case I think it is the problem.  When its cathode is grounded, its Vf is greater than Q2's Vbe, so it is not shunting away 100% of Q2's base current; there still is some current from R2 into the base of Q2.  R2 is so large that Q2 is being "dangle-biased" very slightly on, enough to supply Q1 with a very reduced base current.  As Q1 cools down, its Vbe increases, reducing its own base current even more, until it is starved into non-conduction.

Increase R3, decrease R2, Delete D1.

Reduce the Q2 collector current to 3-5 mA.

Increase the R2 holding current to 0.5-1 mA.

Comment: I`ll have to admit: I should have told you, that this is only part of my circuit - I wanted to try out, if this part is already working. That`s why I have the diode and also the high resistor.
But since your answer explained what I needed to know, I will put an "Accept the answer" to it. Thanks.